# Using Javascript variable in blade conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Ok so I'm creating a calendar and as they days are loading I have to check if there is an event on that day so that it can render in the div for that day. I am doing this by checking in an "if" statement if "i" which is the day in the month is equal to "event_date". Which is being pulled from the DB.

this is my code:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= paddingDays + daysInMonth; i++) {
    const daySquare = document.createElement('div');
    daySquare.classList.add('day');

    const dayString = `${month + 1}/${i - paddingDays}/${year}`;

    if (i > paddingDays) {
      daySquare.innerText = i - paddingDays;

      // const eventForDay = events.find(e => e.date === dayString);

      const eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
      eventDiv.classList.add('event');
      HTMLholder =  `@foreach($events as $event)
                         <div class = "mb-0 text-black">
                             @if($event->event_date == `;
                                 HTMLholder += i;                                 
                                 HTMLholder +=`)

                                 <button class = "bg-green-300 hover:bg-red-700" type = "button">testing</button>
                             @endif
                         </div>
                     @endforeach`;
      eventDiv.innerHTML = HTMLholder;
      daySquare.appendChild(eventDiv);


      if (i - paddingDays === day && nav === 0) {
          daySquare.id = 'currentDay';
      }
```

the issue I'm having is in the "eventDiv.innerHTML". I don't know how to go about comparing "i" to the event->event_date. Please help.

Comment: You cannot mix server side code and client side code.

Comment: 1. blade template/code is processed 2. result is sent to browser 3. HTML is rendered 4. JS scripts run

Comment: The solution is to either a) do everything server-side (PHP/blade) or b) do everything client-side (JS)